# How to create a loadrunner transaction while importing the fiddler save session(.saz) file in loadrunner

Tags: fiddler, loadrunner

I've recorded some steps using Fiddler. 
For example:
Step 1: Open Amazon.com
Step 2: Search Product
Step 3: Add to Cart
Step 4: Select Delivery Address
Step 5: Make Payment

Now for each step, I've given comments in fiddler to differentiate the total number of requests for each step. Post-recording I save the session into a .saz file

Now I import this .saz file into LoadRunner to create the custom requests in LoadRunner. Once the loadrunner file is generated I see that the requests are appearing but I'll have to manually compare the requests from fiddler and check after how many requests a particular step ends and accordingly give the transaction start and transaction stop syntax.

Is there a way by which this process can be automated?
Is there something which we can do in the fiddler before saving the session so that when we import the .saz file in LoadRunner and when the script is generated we either have the transactions created or we get some kind of comments in the LoadRunner after each step via which we can identify easily where each step ends instead of manually comparing each request with Fiddler.

Comment: The comments should appear as comments in the script. Please open a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, will not help you.  Read the license agreement.  Unless you work for Amazon I will not help you violate a licence to build a script that operates against Amazon, violating both the LoadRunner License Agreement and the Amazon license agreement on the use of Automation outside of their published and supported interfaces.

There are plenty of open source tools you can use, installed on servers that you own/control/manage.

Comment: Hi James, if you read properly then you would know im not tryibg to do anything on amazon. It was just an example. Actual script will be created for the client whom i work for. So if you know a way to create transaction automatically after importing the fiddler file to loadrunner then do let me know.

Comment: And a bad example.  There are other examples across the internet which address this same construct.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no way where while importing fiddler also create transactions in LoadRunner on the basis of comments

Comments in fiddler is just makes easy to see which requests corresponds to which action you performed in the browser.